# Show image instead a point in a ChartJS scatter plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to replace points of a scatter plot with a PNG image. Based on the documentation, the `pointStyle` accepts either a string or an image. However instead of the image on the first point, it just shows a regular scatter plot point. Any ideas?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
var img1 = img.src = 'assets/img/small/STORM.png';
var imageData = {
  datasets: [{
    pointStyle: [img1, 'rect', 'triangle', 'circle'],
    data: [{
      x: 1.447377,
      y: -0.014573
    }, {
      x: 2.365398,
      y: -1.062847
    }, {
      x: -2.507778,
      y: 0.389309
    }, {
      x: -0.432636,
      y: 0.124841
    }]
  }]
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: imageData,
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

You can see a working example in [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6rgv71oh/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties), `pointStyle` is either a `string` or an `Image` but not an array.

If you want to have individual [styles](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-styles) for your points, you can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers several hooks that may be used for executing custom code. You could use the `afterDraw` hook to assign a different `pointStyle` to each point.

```
plugins: {
  afterUpdate: function(chart) {
    const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
    meta.data[0]._model.pointStyle = img;
    meta.data[1]._model.pointStyle = 'rect';
    meta.data[2]._model.pointStyle = 'triangle';
    meta.data[3]._model.pointStyle = 'circle';
  }
},
```

I your amended code below, I used a slightly different but more compact approach and defined the `pointStyles` array outside of the chart configuration.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXQrT.png';
const pointStyles = [img, 'rect', 'triangle', 'circle'];

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'scatter',
  plugins: {
    afterUpdate: chart => {
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach((d, i) => d._model.pointStyle = pointStyles[i]);
    }
  },
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        {x: 1.447377, y: -0.014573},
        {x: 2.365398, y: -1.062847}, 
        {x: -2.507778, y: 0.389309},
        {x: -0.432636, y: 0.124841}
      ],
      backgroundColor: ['white', 'green', 'red', 'orange'],
      pointRadius: 10
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```